# Is Plone 5 multilingual?

Tags: plone

Is the version 5 of Plone finally having an official multilingual solution that work? I did try Plone 4 but no multilingual solution was official or was working properly. I hope Plone 5 fix the problem.

Answer (score 8):

plone.app.multilingual is a standard part of Plone 5. After installing Plone 5, activate it via the "add ons" control panel of site setup. Then use the "Languages" control panel to set available languages and translation parameters.

For earlier versions of Plone, install Products.LinguaPlone via the usual add-on package mechanisms. While LinguaPlone does not ship with Plone 4.x, it is a well-supported content-translation mechanism and it does work (though plone.app.multilingual is much better). Translation of Plone's user interface does not require LinguaPlone; it is meant to support content translation.

Both solutions also support adding translation support for custom content types.